# Get local / current file name for docx file using office js

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I have a word add-in and it's been working fine. I need to make a change where, when a user saves the file using "Save-As" and change the file name, I want to retrieve that name in the add-in.

Currently, I get the file name from `Office.context.document.url` which works fine when a document is opened from the web.

But a new local file does not have the `URL` property and I cannot find a way to retrieve the file name. I, however, can assert the file name based on the first paragraph, heading of the file.

Here's a snippet for generating a name from the first paragraph.

```
if (paragraph.text && paragraph.text !== '') {
    let bits = [];
    let para = paragraph.text.toString().split(' ');
    if (para.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
             if (!!para[i]) {
                 nameBits.push(para[i])
              }
        }
         return `${bits.join(' ')}.docx`;
       }
  } else {
      console.warn("No document name found")
      return `New Document.docx`;
  }
```